# How to set different width in textView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I had created a custom `ListView` in which I have added two `TextView`, one of the `TextView` shows the date, and the other `TextView` shows the weight enter on that particular date. Now what I want is that in second `TextView` showing the weights, the width of the text view set as the weight enter by user. The code I have written is showing some issues. This means when users enter the weight 70 and 75 the width of `TextView` shows the same size. why this happen. Please anyone help me to solve this out.

**XML code for List Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img_allnotes_bg" >
       
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_weight_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_divder1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/txt_weight_title"
        android:textColor="#5f5f5f"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_page_text" >
    </TextView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/weight_list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_divider2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" >
    </ListView>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML Code for ListView Item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_weightdate_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#5f5f5f"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_page_text" >
    </TextView>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_weight_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_weightdate_display"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#5f5f5f"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_page_text" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code for Generating List View**

```
public void displayWeights()
{
    m_allWeightsList  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weight_list_view);
            
    int iWeightCount = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getWeightCount();
    
    m_weightsdateDisplay  = new String[iWeightCount];
    
    m_weightDisplay = new String[iWeightCount];
    
    m_enStage = new int[iWeightCount];
    
    int i;      
    
    for (i=0; i<iWeightCount; i++)
    {
        m_weightsdateDisplay[i] = "";

        Date dtWeightDate = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getWeightDate(i);
        
        m_enStage[i] = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getCycleStage(dtWeightDate);

        m_weightsdateDisplay[i] = formator.format(dtWeightDate.getTime());
        
        m_weightDisplay[i] = "";

        m_weightDisplay[i] = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getWeight(dtWeightDate); 
    }
    
    m_adapter = new AllWeightsAdapter(this, m_weightsdateDisplay, m_weightDisplay);

    m_allWeightsList.setAdapter(m_adapter);  
    
}

class AllWeightsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{   
    public String    m_weightsDateDisplay[];
    
    public String    m_weightsDisplay[];

    public Activity  m_context;

    public LayoutInflater  m_inflater;

    public AllWeightsAdapter(Activity m_context, String[] m_weightsDateDisplay, String[] m_weightsDisplay)
    {
        super();

        this.m_context = m_context;

        this.m_weightsDateDisplay = m_weightsDateDisplay;
        
        this.m_weightsDisplay = m_weightsDisplay;

        this.m_inflater = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
    }
    public AllWeightsAdapter()
    {
        
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return m_weightsDateDisplay.length; 
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {   
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txt_weightdt_display;
        
        TextView txt_weight_display;
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
                
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(m_context.getAssets(), "fonts/Cicle Semi.ttf");
        
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_weights_list, null);

            holder.txt_weightdt_display = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_weightdate_display); 
            holder.txt_weight_display = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_weight_display);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        
        // Added Weight Date in List View Component
        holder.txt_weightdt_display.setText(m_weightsDateDisplay[position]);
        holder.txt_weightdt_display.setTypeface(face);
        
        // Added Weights in List View   Component       
        double factor, width, scale, borderwidth, minScreenWidth = 40, maxScreenWidth = 200;
        double maxWeight = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getMaxWeight();
        double minWidth  = CycleManager.getSingletonObject().getMinWeight();  
        
        scale = maxWeight - minWidth;
        factor = (maxScreenWidth - minScreenWidth) / scale;

        width = (maxWeight - Double.parseDouble(m_weightsDisplay[position])) * factor;
        borderwidth = maxScreenWidth - width;

        holder.txt_weight_display.setText(m_weightsDisplay[position]);
        holder.txt_weight_display.setMinWidth((int)borderwidth);
        holder.txt_weight_display.setTypeface(face);
                
        return convertView;
    } 
}
}
```

**Scrennshot**

[image]

Comment: I am guessing the 70 is >= the max size for the view.  Try some values leading up to that like 60, 65.  If so then maybe change your width to half it or something to avoid getting to the max size

Comment: But the View width are wrap content..How to solve my problem so that what ever weight i have entered the width are adjust along that...

Comment: Change your scaling so that it will be smaller length.  You could probably play around with the view as well to give more space for that element

Comment: Which scaling  r talking about..actually i don't found any clue how to solve it..can u please explain me to solve this out

Answer (score 0):

The left/right margins which are 60dps each might be the issue. You are spending 120dps for the empty space. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html says that the screen size for a phone would be 320dp width.

Moreover I am not sure what CycleManager does, but if you do not, may be to define the max you shall use the device screen width and scale accordingly.

Finally, I guess it is not relevant but you are using wrap_content for the listview. Dont you think it is more appropriate to make it fill_parent?

Answer (score 0):

OK @Anshuman it is an issue with screen realistate.  70 and 75 are the same size because you have maxed out the space you have for that view.  Try changing the proportions of that blue marker.  Maybe something like this will give you some more space (just play around with the shrinkScaler variable until you get the size you need to fit all the weights you want.

```
double shrinkScaler = .75;
holder.txt_weight_display.setMinWidth((int)(borderwidth * shrinkScaler));
```